# How to stop using Protobuf-Net inheritance and use inherited classes directly?

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, deserialization, protobuf-net

I have an inherited settings classes inherited from a base class which I would like to (de)serialise separately (example)

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(GlobalSettings))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(UserSettings))]
public class BaseSettings
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class GlobalSettings: BaseSettings
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string TempPath { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class UserSettings: BaseSettings
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int UILanguage { get; set; }
}
```

Only issue is I cannot afford losing the configuration, can it be done in a way that if UserSettings are no longer inherited from BaseSettings and moved to another assembly to be used independently, (de)serialisation still will be possible (with some sort of conversion or without) without access to GlobalSettings class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inheritance is a fundamental part of the serialization model, *especially* if you ever talk in terms of `Deserialize<BaseSettings>`. If you **only ever** do things like `Deserialize<GlobalSettings>` or `Deserialize<UserSettings>`, then you might be able to remove the `[ProtoInclude]`s, but then the issue becomes announcing the members of `BaseSettings` into the sub-types. There are ways to do that.

Comment: I tried creating another base class with [ProtoContract] with only one property [ProtoMember(1)] UserSettings but it did not work. Creating a dummy base class with only [ProtoInclude(1, typeof(UserSettings)] worked fine. Since you not mentioned it I guess there is no ProtoContract option which will "fake" inheritance without adding a dummy base class. Thank you for help.